# How to find out my result table in multiple table search?

Tags: mysql, search

I'm searching in two tables for a string.

```
$sql="SELECT download.title FROM download
      WHERE download.title LIKE '%$search%' 
      UNION 
      SELECT news.title FROM news
      WHERE news.title LIKE '%$search%' OR news.text LIKE '%$search%' ";
```

How can I find out what table the records I have found are from?

Comment: I would query twice, once for each table, instead of using union.

Comment: I dont know if @@Identity can provide information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add a discriminator column in your result-set? That enables you to query once, and get the results by source.

```
SELECT 'DOWNLOAD' AS SOURCE, download.title FROM download WHERE download.title LIKE '%$search%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NEWS', news.title FROM news WHERE news.title LIKE '%$search%' OR news.text LIKE '%$search%';
```

Comment: +1, but you might want to add an alias for your first column.

Comment: Edited SQL and added ALL (for UNION ALL) as it theoretically saves a sort operation :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use [mysql_field_table](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php) function.

Comment: i don't get answer with multiple tables . just when there is one table!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra column to denote the source, which you can then use to determine

e.g.

$

```
sql="SELECT download.title, 'download' as source FROM download WHERE download.title LIKE '%$search%' 
UNION 
SELECT news.title 'news' as source FROM news, WHERE news.title LIKE '%$search%' OR news.text LIKE '%$search%' ";
```

Although as per the earlier comment, querying twice may be better than using union

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to do the query twice, once for each table. Then you would know which one the results were found in. If you want to display them together and sorted, the you could take the two result sets and merge them together before displaying them.